# Macro definition not working when using LuaLaTeX and polyglossia (with `\setmainlanguage{german}`)

Tags: luatex, polyglossia, incompatibility, bm

I'm compiling the following MWE with LuaLaTeX in an updated TexLive 2017 installation on Ubuntu:

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside=semi,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \vec{x} = 1
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Here's what I get:

[image]

The desired output would of course be **x**=1.

Note that this fails only when using `\setmainlanguage{german}`. It also works fine using pdfLaTeX and babel.

```
 *File List*
 scrbook.cls    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script document class (book)
scrkbase.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent basi
cs and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent ba
sics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
tocbasic.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (handling toc-files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2017/09/07 v3.24 KOMA-Script package (type area)
polyglossia.sty    2015/03/25 v1.42.4 Alternative to Babel for XeLaTeX and LuaLa
TeX
etoolbox.sty    2017/01/02 v2.4 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
makecmds.sty    2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
fontspec.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
  xparse.sty    2017/11/14 L3 Experimental document command parser
   expl3.sty    2017/11/14 L3 programming layer (loader) 
expl3-code.tex    2017/11/14 L3 programming layer 
l3pdfmode.def    2017/03/18 v L3 Experimental driver: PDF mode
fontspec-luatex.sty    2017/11/09 v2.6g Font selection for XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX
 fontenc.sty
   tuenc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
fontspec.cfg
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
luatexbase.sty    2015/10/04 v1.3 luatexbase interface to LuaTeX 
ctablestack.sty    2015/10/01 v1.0 Catcode table stable support
gloss-german.ldf    polyglossia: module for german
 babelsh.def    2013/04/30 Babel common definitions for shorthands
 Taken verbatim from babel.def (2013/04/15 v3.9e)
gloss-english.ldf    polyglossia: module for english
  subfig.sty    2005/06/28 ver: 1.3 subfig package
 caption.sty    2016/02/21 v3.3-144 Customizing captions (AR)
caption3.sty    2016/05/22 v1.7-166 caption3 kernel (AR)
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
      bm.sty    2017/01/16 v1.2c Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi)
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
 ***********
```

Comment: Thanks! While that works, I use the `ifluatex` package to make the document compilable with pdfLaTeX too and to conditionally load and configure the engine specific packages in a single `\ifluatex`block. Cluttering commands based on the pickiness of the engine is therefore not what I was hoping for.

Comment: As a general rule, `amsmath`, `amssymb`, and `bm` should always be loaded *before* both `fontspec` and `polyglossia`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `\AtBeginDocument` to delay `\setmainlanguage` (in opposite to `babel` `polyglossia` does language depending catcode changes immediate at least for `german`, so it is somehow recommended to do language selections as late as possible to avoid problems loading other packages or additional preamble definitions):

```
% !TeX program = lualatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside=semi,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setmainlanguage{german}%
  \setotherlanguage{english}%
}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{subfig}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        \vec{x} = 1
    \end{align}
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

[image: work around]

---

BTW: The problem seems to be related to a combination of `lualatex`, `polyglossia` with main language `german`, [`caption`](https://ctan.org/pkg/caption) and `bm`. A MWE would be:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
$\bm{x} = 1$
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

If you use `xelatex` instead of `lualatex` or delay `\setmainlanguage{german}`, e.g., using `\AtBeginDocument`, or load `bm` before `polyglossia` the problem does not longer exist.

So you can also use:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{german}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
$\bm{x} = 1$
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

You should not use `\AtBeginDocument` to load a package, because *unused global options* are reported before execution of the `\AtBeginDocument` hook. And you cannot use `\AtBeginDocument` to load package `csquotes`. But you can use `\AtEndPreamble` of [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), because the corresponding hook is executed at the very beginning of `\begin{document}`:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\AtEndPreamble{\setmainlanguage{german}}
\usepackage{caption}
\AtEndPreamble{\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}}
\begin{document}
$\bm{x} = 1$
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Last but not least, you can use `babel` instead of `polyglossia` to have German as main language and English as second language with `lualatex` too:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\listfiles
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[main=ngerman,english]{babel}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\begin{document}
$\bm{x} = 1$
\end{document}

%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-engine: luatex
%%% TeX-master: t
%%% End:
```

Comment: Any change to make this work when also using `\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}` ? Through trail and error i could not find any place in the preamble to put this without breaking the workaround and throwing `Undefined control sequence. \begin{document}'

Comment: Ah, I did not try putting `csquotes` there as well. When inserting `\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}` in the `\AtBeginDocument` block ofyour first code snippet, I get: `Can be used only in preamble. {}}}` and `Can be used only in preamble. \AtEndPreamble`

Comment: @Christoph90 `csquotes` examples added.

Comment: Thanks! I accepted your answer because of it's completeness for all my additional concerns. Would you consider (for future readers) to move the note about delaying `\setmainlanguage{german}` after the package loading instructions to the top of your post (and even better to point to egregs answer for an explanation)?

Comment: @Christoph90 Using `\AtBeginDocument` (to delay `\setmainlanguage`) was already at the top of my answer. However I've changed it to make it (hopefully) more clear.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Also good advice on babel working with lualatex as well. For some reason I thought polyglossia was required then.

Answer (score 6):

Under LuaLaTeX, the packages `amsmath`, `amssymb`, and `bm` should always be loaded *before* both `fontspec` and `polyglossia`. (It also used to be standard to advise to load `fontspec` after any packages that modify math-related macros -- such as, of course, `amsmath`, `amssymb`, and `bm`. However, at some point in the recent past, an update to `fontspec` has occurred which no longer makes this recommendation a necessity.)

If, for some reason, you simply must load `polyglossia` first, then at least defer the instructions `\setmainlanguage{...}` and `\setotherlanguage{...}` to a point later on in the preamble, i.e., *after* `amsmath`, `amssymb`, `bm` and `fontspec` have been loaded.

Do note that I deliberately started the answer with "Under LuaLaTeX, ...": I'm afraid I have no experience with package loading orderings under XeLaTeX.

The following, modified version of your MWE compiles fine:

```
% !TeX program=lualatex
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside=semi,openright]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,bm}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{polyglossia} % load it *after* amsmath, amssymb, bm, and fontspec
\setmainlanguage{german}
\setotherlanguage{english}

\usepackage{subfig} % it doesn't seem to matter when this package is loaded

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}
\[ \vec{x} = 1 \]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer and thanks for the remark on loading the ams packages first!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that `\setmainlanguage{german}` sets `"` to a shorthand character and loading `bm` after that declaration completely breaks the definitions made by the package when LuaLaTeX is used.

The bizarre string you get is essentially random. Without loading `subfig` you get nothing (but no ***x*** either).

Loading `amsmath` and `bm` before or after `polyglossia` is irrelevant, as long as the language declarations are made *after* package loading.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{subfig}

\setmainlanguage{german}

\renewcommand{\vec}[1]{\bm{#1}}

\begin{document}

$\vec{x}$

\end{document}
```

Try moving `\usepackage{bm}` after `\setmainlanguage{german}` and the issue will appear again.

Comment: Great answer and insight! This is how I actually did it, though it required me to give up on bundling all LuaLaTeX specific commands in a single block and use a second `\ifluatex` `\fi` block after loading both packages to make it compatible with pdfLatex too.
I accepted @Schweinebackes answer, since it did contained the part on moving `\setmainlanguage{german}` (though without the explanation of the actual problem).

Comment: @Christoph90 A well formed preamble should have the package loading separate from the settings part. Mixing them is a sure recipe for code duplication and confusion.

Comment: Is it safe to set package settings via optional arguments on loading then, as for example `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}`?

Comment: @Christoph90 `polyglossia` doesn't fetch languages from document class options; languages are only specified with `\setmainlanguage` and `\setotherlanguage`.